# Using PHP and Bash to log into an external server via SSH

Tags: php, bash, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to set up a centralized server which is in charge of monitoring my other servers. This centralized server needs to be able to collect particular information/metrics about a specific server (such as `df -h` and `service httpd status`); but it also needs to be able to restart Apache if needed.

If it wasn't for the Apache restart, I could write a listening script to provide a means of giving the centralized server the data it needs without having to SSH in. But because I also want it to be able to restart Apache, it needs to be able to log in and initiate scripts through a combination of PHP and Bash.

At the moment, I'm using PHP's [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to execute this (very simple) Bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -i /path/to/keyFile.pem ec2-user@x.x.x.x;
```

I'm accessing the external server (which is an EC2 instance) through a private IP. If I launch this script, I can log in without any problem - the problem comes, however, when I then want to send back the output for commands like the ones I've listed above.

In a Bash script, how would I output a command like `df -h` after SSHing into another server? Is this possible?

Comment: Make a script with the commands u require to run and put it on the server. After ssh, run your script and redirect the output!

Comment: Why not just use something like Zabbix or Nagios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [PECL extension for SSH](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php).

Other than that you'll probably want to either use the `&$output` parameter of `exec()` to grab the output:

```
$output = array();
exec('bash myscript.sh', $output);
print_r($output);
```

Or use output redirection

```
$output = '/path/to/output.txt';
exec("bash myscript.sh > $output");
if( file_exists($output) && is_readable($output) ) {
    $mydata = file_get_contents($output);
}
```

and, of coure, this all assumes your script looks like what jeroen has in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
ssh -i /path/to/keyFile.pem ec2-user@x.x.x.x 'df -h'
```

or for multiple commands:

```
ssh -i /path/to/keyFile.pem ec2-user@x.x.x.x 'ls -al ; df -h'
```

That works from the command line but I have not tried it via php's `exec` (nor on Amazon to be honest...).

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing ssh I'd suggest [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). It's a ton more portable than the PECL SSH extension and more reliable too.